# ResultSet method previous() is not working

Tags: java, jdbc

```
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E)
   {
       int id;
       String name,address,phone;
       Connection conn = null;
       PreparedStatement stmt = null;
       try {
           //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

           //STEP 3: Open a connection
           System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
           conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

           //STEP 4: Execute a query
           String sql;
           sql = "SELECT * FROM person";
           System.out.println("Creating statement...");
           stmt = conn.prepareStatement (sql,ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE , 
                                     ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE );


            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            if(E.getSource()== bNext) {
                rs.next();
                id  = rs.getInt("id");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                address = rs.getString("address");
                phone = rs.getString("phone");

                //Display values
                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", Name: " + name);
                System.out.print(", Address: " + address);
                System.out.println(", Phone: " + phone);
            }
            if(E.getSource()== bPrevious) {
                rs.previous();
                id  = rs.getInt("id");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                address = rs.getString("address");
                phone = rs.getString("phone");

                //Display values
                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", Name: " + name);
                System.out.print(", Address: " + address);
                System.out.println(", Phone: " + phone);
            }
            if(E.getSource()==bLast) {
                rs.last();
                id  = rs.getInt("id");
                name = rs.getString("name");
                address = rs.getString("address");
                phone = rs.getString("phone");

               //Display values
               System.out.print("ID: " + id);
               System.out.print(", Name: " + name);
               System.out.print(", Address: " + address);
               System.out.println(", Phone: " + phone);
           }
           if(E.getSource()==bFirst) {
               rs.first();
               id  = rs.getInt("id");
               name = rs.getString("name");
               address = rs.getString("address");
               phone = rs.getString("phone");

               //Display values
               System.out.print("ID: " + id);
               System.out.print(", Name: " + name);
               System.out.print(", Address: " + address);
               System.out.println(", Phone: " + phone);
          }
          //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();
    }
```

I don't know why, but the `previous()` method is not working and whenever the `next` button is pressed by the user, the output remains the same, and doesn't move forwards. can anyone help please?

Comment: You are creating a new statement every time a button is pressed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each time your `actionPerformed` method is called (I'm assuming it's called when some button is pressed), you execute the query again. Therefore `next()` will always give you the first element and `previous` will return false.

You should probably read all the rows into some data structure such as `ArrayList` (as an initialization step, not when the button is clicked), and maintain the current index of that `List`, which will allow you to move forward or backward when a button is clicked.

P.S. you shouldn't use `rs.next()` or `rs.previous()` without checking the returned value. If those methods return `false`, you should not call methods such as `rs.getInt("id")`, since they will throw an exception.

P.P.S some JDBC drivers don't support the `previous()`, `first` & `last` methods, which means they might throw a `SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`. However, you'll only need `next()` if you read all the data in an initialization step, as I suggested.

Comment: thankyou for guiding me :) :). i am now using the absolute() function instead and storing the row number in static variable and it worked. and yess previous() function is not supported. thankkkyouuu